# How to allow more than one selection in tkinter OptionMenu?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

OptionMenu is working perfectly in my application to select one option among several possible. However, I need to allow the user to select more than one option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not designed for that. If you want that sort of behavior you can create your own widget. An optionmenu is just a menubtton and a menu, and a tiny bit of code.